# Why can I not remove index.php from codeigniter URL

Tags: codeigniter, url, ubuntu, indexing, apache2

I have a new installation of Kubuntu 15.10 with old (working) code from my site.
Somehow I can not get rid of the index.php in the URL.
I tired dozens of suggestions but nothing seems to work. 
My current status is this:

Apache 2 have  mod_rewrite on:
[printout of php_info()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZVQL.png)

Apache2 config is:

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My .htaccess is located under application folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    # Hide the application and system directories by redirecting the request to index.php
    RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

What am I missing here? I am loosing faith... :-P

Comment: Read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/09/how-to-remove-index-php-file-from-codeigniter-url/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: In your **.htaccess** replace all other codes..try with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(application) - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Step 2: Move your **.htaccess** from **application folder** to where **index.php** located.

Step 3: Change in your `config.php`

From:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: Tank you! The problem was the .htaccess file needs to be in the same folder as the index.php file.  All the rest was OK . Akmost decided to abandon CI... Thanks again.

Comment: I have done this same thing on Ubuntu 14.04. It doesn't work. I also have mod_rewrite on. What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try it in application/.htaccess, index.php will exists in url but in scripts it will be ignored.

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Comment: in above code method you will receive 404 error if URL contain index.php